# python3 (nltk/numpy/etc): ISO efficient way to compute find pairs of similar strings

Tags: python, string, numpy, nltk, similarity

I have a list of N strings. My task is to find all pairs of strings that are sufficiently similar. That is, I need (i) a similarity metric that would produce a number in a predefined range (say between 0 and 1) that measures how similar the two strings are and (ii) a way of going through O(N^2) pairs quickly to find those that are above some sort of threshold (say >= 0.9 if the metric gives larger numbers for more similar strings). What I am doing now is pretty slow (as one might expect) for a large N:

```
import difflib

num_strings = len(my_strings)
for i in range(num_strings):
    s_i = my_strings[i]

    for j in range(i+1,num_strings):
        s_j = my_strings[j]
        sim = difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=s_i, b=s_j).ratio()
        if sim >= thresh:
            print("%s\t%s\t%f" % (s_i,s_j,sim))
```

Questions:

1. What would be a good way of vectorizing this double loop to speed it
   up maybe using NLTK, numpy or any other library?
2. Would you recommend a better metric than difflib's ratio (again, from NLTK, numpy etc)?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe try this: https://gist.github.com/alvations/a4a6e0cc24d2fd9aff86

Comment: Could you post the full list of strings that you would like to deal with?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the optimal solution you have to be O(n^2), if you want an approximate of the optimal solution you can select a threshold and delete pairs that have a fair similarity ratio.
I would suggest you use another metrics since you're adding complexity with the difflib's ratio (it depends on the length of the strings). These ratio could be entropy or manhattan/euclidean distance.

Comment: (i) I am not sure I understand your first remark. I need to do O(N^2) similarity calculations even if I come up with some fast heuristics to quickly identify pairs that will have very low or very high similarity. The question is whether I can do it much faster than with the above double loop. (ii) Can you recommend a specific metric to replace the ratio?

Comment: My first remark considers that in order to find a "satisfying enough" pair you do not have to compare each element with all the elements left in your list. As for another metric you can go with the hamming distance : `scipy.spatial.distance.hamming(u, v)`

Comment: if u and v are supposed to be character lists representing strings then this won't work for strings of different lengths, which I can't exclude

Comment: Therefore you can look at the Levenshtein distance [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) [python](https://www.python-course.eu/levenshtein_distance.php)

Comment: Levenshtein gives a distance measured in numbers of tokens (chars, words etc). I am looking for a normalized metric in a predefined range (e.g. between 0 and 1) so that I can threshold it

Comment: maybe you could try to look for a normalized [Levenshtein](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17431306)